# How to to concat multiple ranges views

Tags: c++, string-concatenation, std-ranges, c++23

Code compiles with g++14. I would like to know if there is a way to avoid calling ranges::to() so many times.

I was thinking maybe there is a way to use a tuple instead of a vector to accomodate such ranges of different types (if they hadn't been converted to string).

```
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>
#include <format>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::literals;

struct Point
{
    int x, y;
};


struct Polyline
{
    int from;
    int to;
    vector<Point> data;
};

int main()
{
    const vector<Polyline> polylines = {
        {.from=0, .to=1, .data={{.x=2,.y=2},{.x=4,.y=4}}},
        {.from=1, .to=2, .data={{.x=20,.y=20},{.x=40,.y=40}}}   
    };
    
    auto il = {
        "["s,
        polylines | views::transform([](auto arg){
            auto [from, to, data]=arg;
            auto il = {
                "{"s,
                R"("polyline":)"s,
                "["s,
                data | views::transform([](auto arg){auto [x, y]=arg;   return format(R"({{"x":{}, "y":{}}})", x, y);})
                    | views::join_with(',')
                    | ranges::to<string>(),
                "],"s,
                format(R"("from":{},"to":{})", from, to),
                "}"s
                };
            return il | views::join | ranges::to<string>();
        }) | views::join_with(",\n"s) | ranges::to<string>(),
        "]"s
    };
    
    string buffer = il | views::join_with('\n') | ranges::to<string>();
}
```

Comment: Is this C++20 or C++23? `join_with` is from C++23

Comment: Which compiler are you using that supports `ranges::to`? **g++ (GCC) 13.2.1 20230801** does not support it. Also `il` is shadowed -- is that intentional?

Comment: Please describe what you want to do first instead of asking a question that falls from the sky.